# Connect Facebook Pixel with Facebook analytics

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

We are currently integrating Facebook Pixel to track some events in our web site.
In the Pixel dashboard we are able to see the events we are sending but we are not 
able to see the associated parameters. Could you provide us with a link/guide where we 
can see these parameters?
Another doubt we have regards the possibility to have a centralized dashboard for the analytics. 
We currently use mobile analytics and we would like to have all the events both from web 
and mobile in one place. Is this possible?

I've created a new facebook app called otello_test.
In the settings page I can see an option for mapping Pixels but I can't do nothing with it.  When I click on the info button and then click on "Learn More" there is only a redirect page without any type of content.

EDIT:

This is a simple event on my web site

```
fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
            content_name: 'Really Fast Running Shoes',
            content_category: 'Apparel > Accessories > Shoes',
            content_ids: ['1234'],
            content_type: 'product',
            value: 4.99,
            currency: 'USD'
        });
```

First of all i can't see any parameter that i've send on my pixel dashboard. 
 http://imageshack.com/a/img921/6300/gCbzuz.png

Why ?

About the analytics error:
http://imageshack.com/a/img921/9459/up9ZNS.png

As you can see in the settings there is a specific area for mapping pixels but when i click on "Scopri di più(Learn More)" there's no documentation available for it.

Comment: We will need some relevant code or images to be able to help you. We need more context. Also, please try to ask one question at a time.

Comment: I have the same issue. I am setting these parameters (content_name, content_type) and the tracking code is working, but I can't see any of these parameters in the dashboard. Did you eventually find them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Official Chrome extension called [Facebook Pixel Helper](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/pixel-helper?hc_location=ufi) to help you validate your Facebook Pixel.

### To See Event Parameters in Facebook Analytics

1. Select the "Activity" section in left navigation list.
2. Select the "Events" section.
3. Select the Pre-defined or Custom Event you want to view.
4. You can then either apply a segment on these charts using the "Add a Segment" in the top bar to segment the data displayed by the parameters, or you can select the "Show By" option on the graph and select the parameters to see if they're collecting data.

### Omni-channel (Cross Platform) Dashboard/Insights

To have a centralized dashboard for multiple channels (web, mobile, etc.) you would want to set up an Event Source Group. Documentation located [here](https://www.intern.facebook.com/help/analytics/1387547017939527?helpref=search&sr=1&query=omni%20channel).

**How To Set Up an Event Source Group**

1. From the first row of the menu on the left, click on the name of the event source or event source group that is currently displayed.
2. Click + New Event Source Group.
3. Select the Business Manager account that you'd like to create your event source group from, then click Continue. Keep in mind that only admins in Business Manager can currently create event source groups.
4. Name your event source group.
5. Select the event sources (Web [FB Pixel], App, etc.) to add to this group.
6. Click Create Group.

You will now be able to see Omni-channel (cross channel) insights in one central view and create dashboards as well.